# Linq wont return List

Tags: c#, linq

```cs
public IEnumerable<ProfileVM> GetEmployees()
{
    var register2 = from a in context.Employees
                    join b in context.Accounts on a.NIK equals b.NIK
                    select new
                    {
                        a.NIK,
                        b.Password,
                    };
    return register2.ToList();
}
```

I have a Repository to call data using LINQ, I want to return it so I can pass it to my controller, but I can't return it

```cs
return (IEnumerable<ProfileVM>)register2.ToList();
```

The IDE suggest this but it still doesn't work the error said :

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType8`3[System.String,System.String,System.Int32]]'
> to type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[API.ViewModel.ProfileVM]'.'

MyProfileVM

```cs
public class ProfileVM
{
    public string NIK { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int GPA { get; set; }
    public string Degree { get; set; }
    public int UniversityId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your Linq query doesn't return any `ProfileVM` objects: it returns a new anonymous-typed object. What is the definition of `ProfileVM`?

Comment: I already edit my question, now it include profileVM

Comment: Have you tried this? `select new ProfileVM { Nik = a.Nik, Password = b.Password }`

Comment: @YongShun Your solution Work well on my problem, I don't know if we need to select ProfileVM, thankyou

Comment: Why is `Password` a `String` property?

Comment: @Dai isn't it because the password can contain any char? what property that password should use ?

Comment: select new ProfileVM { Nik = a.Nik, Password = b.Password } will work, however the other properties in ProfileVM will have empty / null default values.

Comment: @BagoesHeikhal It implies you're storing passwords as plaintext in your database, which is **a huge no-no**.

Comment: @Dai can i know why?

Comment: @BagoesHeikhal https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `GetEmployees()` returns the value with `IEnumerable<ProfileVM>` type, your LINQ statement is expected to return set of `ProfileVM`(s) [concrete type] as below:

```cs
public IEnumerable<ProfileVM> GetEmployees()
{
    var register2 = from a in context.Employees
                    join b in context.Accounts on a.NIK equals b.NIK
                    select new ProfileVM
                    {
                        Nik = a.NIK,
                        Password = b.Password
                    };
    return register2.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the properties is mapping your view model. Then try add your class*(Your case is ProfileVM)* to the linq select new.

```
        public IEnumerable<ProfileVM> GetEmployees()
        {
            var register2 = from a in context.Employees
                            join b in context.Accounts on a.NIK equals b.NIK
                            join c in context.Profilings on b.NIK equals c.NIK
                            select new ProfileVM
                            {
                                a.NIK,
                                b.Password,
                                c.EducationId
                            };
            return register2.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: the problem with this code is that `ProfileVM` specifies 12+ properties but this query only populates 3 of them. Callers of `GetEmployees()` aren't going to know that (for example) `ProfileVM.Degree` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
public IEnumerable<ProfileVM> GetEmployees()
    {
        var register2 = from a in context.Employees
                        join b in context.Accounts on a.NIK equals b.NIK
                        select new
                        {
                            a.NIK,
                            b.Password,
                        };
        return register2.ToList();
    }
```

Try

```
public IEnumerable<ProfileVM> GetEmployees()
    {
        var register2 = from a in context.Employees
                        join b in context.Accounts on a.NIK equals b.NIK
                        select new ProfileVM()
                        {
                            NIK = a.NIK,
                            Password = b.Password,
                        };
        return register2.ToList();
    }
```